# How to Upload XFile image to Firebase Storage in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, flutter-web

The code that is working on Mobile Devices.

```dart
final profileImageFile = await _profileImage.readAsBytes();
        if (!kIsWeb) {
          try {
            await ref
                .putData(
                  profileImageFile,
                  fbSorage.SettableMetadata(
                    contentType: 'image/png',
                  ),
                )
                .whenComplete(() {});
          } on Exception catch (e) {
            print(e);
            return;
          }
        }
```

The `_profileImage` is the `XFile` When trying on the web, the uploaded file is corrupted.

```dart
The following DomException object was thrown resolving an image codec:
  EncodingError: The source image cannot be decoded.
```

I used the `universal_html` package to upload a `html.Blob` using `putBlob` method:

```dart
if (kIsWeb) {
          await ref
              .putBlob(
                html.Blob(profileImageFile),
                fbSorage.SettableMetadata(
                  contentType: 'image/png',
                ),
              )
              .whenComplete(() {});
        }
```

Same exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue and this link helped me:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example
Just set the metadata:

```
final metadata = SettableMetadata(
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': file.path},
);

if (kIsWeb) {
  uploadTask = ref.putData(await file.readAsBytes(), metadata);
} else {
  uploadTask = ref.putFile(io.File(file.path), metadata);
}
```